# Plunker bad request with status code 400

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, bad-request, plunker

In Plunker I get this error message in my live preview:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "content must be a string",
  "validation": {
    "source": "payload",
    "keys": [
      "files.js.content"
    ]
  }
}
```

It used to be working correctly last week. I see the same or similar 400 live preview message on any page I visit. [Here is the link to my plunker page](http://plnkr.co/edit/W0Y7Joh1mcBXNuFtNnXe?p=preview). Does anyone have similar issue with plunker recently?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question concerns the status of an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

This was the result of a bug that was temporarily deployed to production. It has now been resolved.